# Create password and authentication for existing users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have rails app with:
Admin table with Devise authentication
User table with email and name without authentication (but session to remember them)

User can browse anywhere but now on certain pages I would like to enhance it and add authentication - allow user to create password and only with password it will be accessible but I am quite lost what is the best way to do it with the current setting?

I allow users to add their details like name and email and I am creating a cookie to remember them without any authentication or password:

```
  UsersController

  def create
    user = User.find_or_create_by(email: params[:user][:email])
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    session[:user_id] = user.id # for users/edit temporary
    render json: user
  end
```

Let's say I have this following method in User:
      before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :your_order
      def your_order
      end

If User will visit this page and didn't set up password before, how can I prompt him to create one and how can I require for him to login after with Devise? I am thinking of more solutions but none of them are perfect.

Comment: You can add a password column to the User. Then add a filter that checks something like `current_user.password.empty?`. If it's true you can send them to a page where the User can create a password. You can also set up a filter that checks whether the user is logged in. Since you're already using cookies for this User model, maybe you should consider creating another model like AuthenticatedUser, and that's where users will save their password, login, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per the specifications given the below mentioned criteria might help you.

```
def your_order #before_filter
  if user.password.present?
   # authenticate using valid_password? method of devise
 else
   #redirect user to say set_password 
 end
end

def set_password
 #set the user password in this method and after successful completion redirect to login page where before filter your_order will be called
end
```